# Git clone issues on debian

Tags: git, bitbucket

Lets give a brief summary first. All my private repositories are saved on BitBucket and i check these out using Git Tower on OSX, i also have a local development server running debian that i am connected to using samba.

Now the problem i am getting has only just started happening and as far as i know nothing has been changed to the linux server.

I check out the project to the linux server, once done i check the files and all of them are saying they have been modified even though i just checked out the project. If i check it out to my mac desktop and check the files its all fine.

What would be causing this?

I appreciate any help.

Regards,

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git does not store and/or preserve file creation/modification times, so what you are seeing is normal unless I'm missing something.

Comment: The project has only just been checked out so it should have 0 modified files.

Comment: What modification are you referring to? file modification timestamp, or `git status` output? If the former, that's normal... if the latter, what does `git diff` show the differences are?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but if i check the file with the diff tool it says 'File Mode changed to 100775 (Executable File)'

Comment: Aha... are you checking out the files on the Mac, into the samba share? or on the samba server itself via ssh or similar? It smells a lot like the file permissions mask used by your Mac when mounting the samba share. The SMB protocol doesn't do unix file permissions, so a unix host mounting a SMB share needs to map these to something sane. Often, that's to something similar to what you mention above.